# How can I give autoplay in fancybox images?

Tags: javascript

I am using fancybox plugin for gallery. I don't know how can i give auto play slideshow images. Please help me.

```
<li><a href="images/galimage12big.jpg" class="quick_view" data-fancybox="quick-view8" data-qw-form="qw-form-8">
            <img src="images/galimage12new.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="caption-text">
                    <h1>Healthcare and pharmaceuticals Industry</h1>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </a>
```

Comment: On a small, but important, note: autoplaying carousels are a really bad idea unless they are _exceptionally_ implemented, with accessibility and navigation stability in mind. It's still your site, but unless your site somehow unambiguously gives users the expectation of an autoplaying slideshow: don't autoplay.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please share the JS part where you are initialized fancybox plugin

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://inuson.com/new/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>